# What is the best combination of airfoil shape for flight in ground effect over water?

Tags: aircraft-design, lift, wing-tip-vortex

What is the best airfoil shape for flight in ground effect over water?

Comment: Why closed? The principle of [GE vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_vehicle) is well known. Which airfoil, which angle of attack to use are valid questions. An [hydrofoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrofoil) is similar to an airfoil. Related: [Wing in Ground (WIG) Effect Vehicles](http://dynlab.mpe.nus.edu.sg/mpelsb/AEG/WIG/ATSNGH.pdf).

Comment: In my opinion it's unclear because it has several questions, each of which has minor problems.  Overall the question fits the "What's your favorite?" or “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?” types that are listed as questions to avoid.  My suggestion would be to break up or simplify the question so it's clear what you really want to know.  Another way to improve it might be to focus on how you choose the airfoil, not what you should choose, or instead provide specific acceptance criteria so we know what exactly you mean by "best airfoil".

Comment: I would second @CodyP 's suggestion.  This needs to be broken up into a few questions so that all issues can be addressed separately (possibly with links between them.)

Comment: The question is still vague.   By best, do you mean most widely used, highest coefficient of lift, or best lift to drag ratio?  How important is it to have aerodynamic center and coefficient of lift relatively constant for various heights?  What are the operating speeds (Reynolds number), angle of attack, and ground clearance are we talking about?  Typical Reynolds numbers can range from 3*10^5 to 2*10^6, angle of attack might be 4 degrees, and ground clearance between 5 to 100% of the chord length

Comment: This question has been the subject of a lot of research over the years. You may find [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/archive/2014/931232/) in particular to be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: Optimal airfoil shape has nothing to do with the fact whether the aircraft is ground effect or not. What matters is getting the minimum drag for the operating CL

Answer (score 4):

There are three considerations for this design:

1. Airfoil shape
2. Aspect ratio
3. Dihedral/Anhedral

Airfoil shape: high lift undercambered thick and very forgiving - good idea near the ground
      Gottingen 436, NACA 4412

Low aspect ratio: lower stall speed, better compression lift from ground effect, more 
     stable in pitch

Anhedralled wings:  this actually provides more roll stability in ground effect as the 
      LOWER wing has more lift.  Anhdralling also helps "trap" more air underneath the wings
      for greater lift.

Ground effect designs would be similar for travel over flat land or water.  Good info in links 
provided by @mins and @Juan Jimenez.

Comment: The Achilles Heel of WIG is the instability in pitch as the plane comes out of ground effect and the center of pressure moves forward. Planform shape is a real target of opportunity for making WIG more usable.

Comment: Spruce Goose seemed to do OK.  Not sure about that reverse Delta, or constantly flying low.

Comment: I think it left performance gains on the table, though. Anyway, WIGs are cool.